# Lodash _.filter how to find siblings in array of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm not having any luck identifying an object defined in an array inside and array.

I have the following data

```
var values = 
[
  {
  "letter": "S",
  "clients": [
    {
      "_id": "58f61681e32f1927a41c19bf",
      "firstName": "Shelly",
      "lastName": "R",
    }
  ]
  },
  {
  "letter": "G",
  "clients": [
      {
        "_id": "58f2ab99319e35299b1ee4a9",
        "firstName": "Gary",
        "lastName": "R",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and the following lodash call.

```
var identifier = '58f2ab99319e35299b1ee4a9';
var v =  _.filter(values, {clients: [{_id: identifier}]});
```

which i read should work with nested arrays.
am i missing something here?

well i'm using this _.filter in a angular component routing scenario.

although values.clients object contains more information. i substituted that fiddle with the actual output and it worked. returned an instance. however code below does not.

```
}).state('clients.client', {
        url: '/{clientId}',
        component: 'client',
            resolve: {
                    client : function(rolodex, $stateParams, _){
                        //var values = rolodex;
                        //console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
                        var identifier = $stateParams.clientId;

                        var v =  _.filter(rolodex, {clients: [{_id: identifier}]});
                        console.log(v[0].clients[0]);
                        return v[0].clients[0];
                    }
            }
    });
```

G.

I guess i spoke to soon, this lodash script does not work correctly.
If i my secondary array contains more than one entry i get both entries in my result set.

```
[
  {
    "letter": "C",
    "clients": [
      {
        "_id": "58f6b8a932edbb7dd718f05a",
        "firstName": "Casie",
        "lastName": "L"
      },
      {
        "_id": "58f68b0d527cc336a8f86cc8",
        "firstName": "Chad",
        "lastName": "M"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "letter": "G",
    "clients": [
      {
        "_id": "58f2ab99319e35299b1ee4a9",
        "firstName": "Gary",
        "lastName": "R"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "letter": "J",
    "clients": [
      {
        "_id": "58f6b90032edbb7dd718f05c",
        "firstName": "Jett",
        "lastName": "F"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "letter": "S",
    "clients": [
      {
        "_id": "58f61681e32f1927a41c19bf",
        "firstName": "Shelly",
        "lastName": "R"
      },
      {
        "_id": "58f6b8d632edbb7dd718f05b",
        "firstName": "Shirley",
        "lastName": "A"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

gives me the correct array containing the correct _id.

```
[
    {
        "letter": "S",
        "clients": [
            {
                "_id": "58f61681e32f1927a41c19bf",
                "firstName": "Shelly",
                "lastName": "R"
            },
            {
                "_id": "58f6b8d632edbb7dd718f05b",
                "firstName": "Shirley",
                "lastName": "A"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

but i would like my result to look like this.

```
{
    "_id": "58f61681e32f1927a41c19bf",
    "firstName": "Shelly",
    "lastName": "R"
}
```

this may be my answer.

```
var b = _(data).thru(function(col1){
return _.union(col1, _.map(col1, 'clients'));
})
.flatten()
.find({_id : '58f61681e32f1927a41c19bf'});
```

Comment: This is agnostic of Angular.

Comment: this should work, [check here](https://jsfiddle.net/6qLze9ub/40/)

Comment: your correct it does work there, but it seems not too in my code. brb

Comment: that fiddle is using lodash 3.6  i'm using 4.17.4

Comment: okay substituted 4.17.4 for 3.6 and it works, must be some changes

Comment: After testing with a staggered secondary array of clients this does not work as anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

this approach seems to work for the mean time.

```
var b = _(data).thru(function(col1){
return _.union(col1, _.map(col1, 'clients'));
})
.flatten()
.find({_id : '58f61681e32f1927a41c19bf'});
```